# Gettings the `which application` output in Bash

Tags: mac-osx, bash

Here is my original [question at StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435015/how-to-get-path-to-the-installed-git-in-python)

This is the script I wrote

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
GP=`/usr/bin/which git`
PWD=`pwd`
echo "PATH IS: ${GP}"
echo "PWD IS: ${PWD}"
```

and output is

```
PATH IS: 
PWD IS: /Users/user/tmp
```

So the question is how to get `which git` output? I'm running it on Mac OS X 10.6.2.

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but why do u have #!/usr/bin/env bash at the beginning, shouldn't u use #!/usr/bin/bash?

Comment: First, I'd assume that 'which' is in your path (and if it isn't, you can safely assume your path is screwed up, which means that 'which' won't work right anyway), so I'd remove the absolute path. Does running 'which git' work from the command line? Also, the curley braces aren't strictly necessary in that particular case. You could just say echo "PATH IS: $GP" and it will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

If `git` isn't located in a directory listed in your `$PATH` variable, `which` will be unable to locate it.

The `PATH` is affected by the following circumstances:

- Login shell
- Non-interactive (login) shell
- Rootshell

Typically specified in `/etc/profile`.  Also can be affected by `~/.bashrc` for a non-interactive shell and `~/.bash_profile` for a login shell.

Comment: to debug, add  echo "\$PATH IS: ${PATH}"

Comment: On osx, also check ~/.profile.

Answer (score 1):

Use `type` (a Bash builtin) instead of `which`:

```
gp=$(type -P git)
```

If you use `type -a` the result will show aliases, functions and more than one executable if alternates exist. You can parse the output if necessary.

Don't set `PWD` - it's already set by Bash. In fact, I recommend not using all-caps variable names in order to avoid naming collisions with Bash's variables.

```
# no need to set PWD, it's already set by Bash
echo "PWD IS: ${PWD}"
```